# Update an image with one by one

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update image in one by one.

Example : I want to update only IMG1.

[image]

img1 : `img_id = 1, img_name = demo1.jpg`

img2 : `img_id = 2, img_name = demo2.jpg`

When I press update button with only IMG1 it should send `img_id = 1` to `$id = $_POST['image_id'];` But it send `img_id = 2` Then will make IMG2 has been update not IMG1.

updateimage.php

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="text-center">
      <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT img_id, img_name FROM fm_product_image WHERE p_id_img = '$ID'")or die(mysql_error()); ?>
      <?php while ($imagerows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $imgid = $imagerows['img_id']; ?>
         <img class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" style="border-radius: 2px; width: 70%;" src="upload/<?php echo $imagerows['img_name']; ?>">
         <h6>Upload your product image.</h6>
         <input type="file" name="image" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
         <input type="text" required value="<?php echo $imgid; ?>" name="image_id" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
         <button type="submit" name="image" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: auto;">Update</button>
         <br>
         <br>
      <?php } ?>
   </div>
</div>
<?php
$id = $_POST['image_id'];
if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
    $image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $size = $_FILES["image"] ["size"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);          
    $product_img = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    mysql_query(" UPDATE fm_product_image SET img_name = '$product_img' WHERE img_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
    header('location:product.php'); 
} ?>
```

Comment: So what is the question/problem?

Comment: Code becomes much more readable if you store the results of php operations in variables and insert only these in your html. Better yet separate html and php completely.

Comment: @Andrew I can't update only img1 when I update img1 but img2 will be changed too.

Comment: are you aware that you should not use `mysql_query` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 
My code has send last record like 1,2,3 it will send 3 to $_POST['image_id'];. How to fix it to send IDs that I want to update like I want to update img_id 1 when I click update it will send 1 to $_POST['image_id'];

Comment: It's not clear what you want: When I click on the update button below imageX, then img_id will be X, but what should be the img_name? X+2?

Comment: So sorry, I'll explain in clear can we talk in chat? Please help me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your loop. You are submitting the same form, and that form contains the text fields which each image's ID. So, even if you have ten images, the IDs for all ten will be submitted, and the server will most likely use the last ID, which would be 10, and update that one.

The solution is to create a form on each iteration of your loop, that way, when you hit the submit button, it submits only the form containing the ID of a given image. Here is a solution below:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT img_id, img_name FROM fm_product_image WHERE p_id_img = '$ID'")or die(mysql_error()); ?>

<?php while ($imagerows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?> 

   <?php $imgid = $imagerows['img_id']; ?>
   <img class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" style="border-radius: 2px; width: 70%;" src="upload/<?php echo $imagerows['img_name']; ?>">
    <h6>Upload your product image.</h6>
    <form method="post" action="YOUR_ACTION_PAGE" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="image" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
       <input type="text" required value="<?php echo $imgid; ?>" name="image_id" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
       <button type="submit" name="image" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: auto;">Update</button>
     </form>
     <br>
     <br>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Notice I created a new form on each iteration through the loop.

I must also mention that you need to consider switching to the better and safer mysqli_* family of functions.

Comment: The way your currently implement it, when the form is submitted, all IDs will be submitted along with it. That's the reason you create a different form on each iteration. And yes, you should create a different form for the update code.

Comment: I've got a problem can't send $_POST['image'] or $_FILES["image"]["name"].

Comment: Can I see how you implemented my form? I mean, where are you posting the form to? I hope you are not using the literal "YOUR_ACTION_PAGE"?

Comment: I move update code to my new created file -> update_image.php.

Comment: I meant, the action page of the form, where is it pointing to? There is nothing wrong with the code you just showed me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101651/discussion-between-butter-toast-and-naijaprogrammer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot have multiple inputs of type text / file with the same name attribute in the same form tag or in the DOM in there is no form tag around the inputs.

To solve this problem, right after you open the while, add a form with a different name (e.g. name of the image that you want updated) and right before closing the while loop, close the form tag.

**EDIT:**

This is what I was talking about.

```
<?php while ($imagerows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $imgid = $imagerows['img_id']; ?>
   <form name="update_<?php echo $imagerows['img_name']; ?>_form" method="post">
     <img class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" style="border-radius: 2px; width: 70%;" src="upload/<?php echo $imagerows['img_name']; ?>">
     <h6>Upload your product image.</h6>
     <input type="file" name="image" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
     <input type="text" required value="<?php echo $imgid; ?>" name="image_id" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">
     <button type="submit" name="image" class="btn btn-success" style="margin: auto;">Update</button>
     <br>
     <br>
   </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `<input name="name[]" />` is perfectly valid and will create an array in `$_POST`

Comment: @DarkBee true, but using that form still doesn't solve the problem.